Who is eligible for Bramha jnana?
Is it true that, as I read somewhere, only those who are versed in the four vedas and self-controlled are eligible for bramha jnana?

Tattva Bodha, written by Ādhi Sankrāchārya, gives us knowledge of the precise definitions of terms that would
used in the study of Vedanta. Tattva Bodha explains clearly who are eligible or qualifies for Ātma Jnānam(आत्मज्ञानम्/aka Brahma Jnānam/ब्रह्मज्ञानम्).
Anybody who aspires moksha(मोक्ष/Liberation) is eligible for Ātma Jnānam/Brahma Jnānam.

साधनचतुष्टयं किम्? नित्यानित्यवस्तुविवेकः।
इहामुत्रार्थ फलभोगविरागः शमादिषट्कसंपित्तिः।
मुमुक्षुत्वं चेति॥

Sādhana catuṣṭayaṁ kiṁ?
Nityānityavastu vivēkaḥ. Ihāmutrārthaphalabhōga virāgaḥ.
Śamādi Ṣaṭka sampattiḥ. Mumukṣutvam cēti.

What is the four fold requirement [eligibility] for self-knowledge [Atma Jnanam/Brahma Jnanam]?

1. Nitya-Anitya Vastu Vivekam [The capacity to discriminate between the permanent and the impermanent], 
2. Virāga [Dispassion to the enjoyment of the fruits of one's actions here and hereafter], 
3. Samādhi Satka Sampathi[The group of six accomplishments beginning with Sama].
4. Mumukṣutvam [The yearning for liberation].

- Tattvabodha Ch-1, sloka-2


Please read my Quora post which is based completely on Tatva Bhodam (तत्व बोधम्/Philosophy of Truth) written by Ādi Sankarāchārya describes the fourfold qualifications known as Sādhana chatushtayam (साधन चतुष्टय/சாதன சதுஷ்டயம்)  in detail required for the enquiry into the nature of reality (Ātma Vichāra/आत्मा विचार) in order to attain ātmajñānam (आत्मज्ञानम्/aka ब्रह्मज्ञानम्) that leads to Moksha(मोक्ष/Liberation).
Conclusion:
I take this opportunity to appeal to the Readers of StackExchange Hinduism to study a little Vedantic Granta called Tatva Bhodam (तत्व बोधम्/Philosophy of Truth or Reality/தத்வ போதம்) written by Ādhi Sankra (आदि सङ्कर/ஆதி சங்கரர்), at least once in your life time, to know about Brahman(ब्रह्मन्/परमात्मन्/Absolute Truth/Supreme Spirit/Paramātman).

Tatva Bhodam (तत्व बोधम्/Philosophy of Truth) written by Ādhi Sankrāchārya.

This granta explains lucidly not only about Relationship between Human and Brahman unparalleled to any other text (अद्वैधम्/Advaidam/Never Two but One/இரண்டல்ல ஓன்று) but also about Karma and three of its forms. Study of this little granta facilitates to sharpen our basic knowledge on Vedānta Darshana.
Though the size of this Vedāntic Granta, in terms of number of Sūtras, is little like Mustard but not short of chilli (கடுகு சிறுத்தாலும் காரம் குறையாது)!
Good Luck!
